# update dataGridView in winform app

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, dataset

I have in my winform app a dataGridView and I displayed the data from the DAL class with dataSet like this

```
DataSet ds2 = DAL.Display_all();
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds2;
dataGridView1.DataMember = "To_display";
```

How can I update Back my  data if If someone change data in the gridView ( I need to  sand back to the DAL class)?

Comment: What are you doing at DAL.Display_all()? The dataset automaticaly updates with the DataGridView.

Comment: I think he's asking how to get the updated rows and update his database?

Comment: i have an sql query with open connection, and i return dataSet from the DAL,then I do the above mentioned

Comment: what about listining to DataTable.TableNewRow, DataTable.RowChanged, DataTable.RowDeleted?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`DataAdapter.Update`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dataadapter.update.aspx) method.

Pass the `DataSet` as the parameter.

You can use [`DataSet.HasChanges`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zky7370c.aspx) to see if you have any changes before calling the Update method.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
dataGridView1.ResetBindings();
```

> Causes a control bound to the BindingSource to reread all the items in the list and refresh their displayed values. MSDN

hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

If you loop through each row of the DataGridView you can use the below method to get the value of a specified Column on a specific row.

```
    private T GetDataGridViewTextBoxValue<T>(int rowIndex, string columnName)
    {
        try
        {
            return (T)Convert.ChangeType(dataGridViewImport.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[columnName].Value, typeof(T));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(String.Format("Row : {0}, column : {1} could not be cast to {2}", rowIndex, columnName, typeof(T)), e);
        }
    }
```

And you can use the method like this.

```
for(int i=0;i< ds2.Tables[0].Rows.Count(); i++)
{
    var column1 = GetDataGridViewTextBoxValue<string>(i, "column1");
    //Get the rest of the row values.
    //In your DAL class you must have a Method that updates the row 
    //and then just pass in the values that you want.
}
```